# More Blurred With RenderScript In Android

Tags: android, background, android-drawable, blur, blurry

For my project i want to use blurred backgrounds.When i use the following method,it does my background blur but it is not blurred enough for me,i want to do more blurry background.I set the radius as its maximum value 25.Someone can help me ?

```
private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.9f;
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 25.0f;

public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

    return outputBitmap;


}
```

Comment: are you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If using a blur radius of 25 is still not enough, one cheap way to do blur is to resize the background image down and then resize it up.

```
private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.9f;
private static final float RESIZE_SCALE = 1.f/5.f;
private static RenderScript rs;

public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

    if (rs == null) {
        // Creating a RS context is expensive, better reuse it.
        rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    }
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);

    Type t = Type.createXY(mRS, tmpIn.getElement(), width*RESIZE_SCALE, height*RESIZE_SCALE);
    Allocation tmpScratch = Allocation.createTyped(rs, t);

    ScriptIntrinsicResize theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicResize.create(rs);
    // Resize the original img down.
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach_bicubic(tmpScratch);
    // Resize smaller img up.
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpScratch);
    theIntrinsic.forEach_bicubic(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

    return outputBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Miao,decreasing BITMAP_SCALE like 0.3f,my image blurred so much.

Comment: Yeah, that's doing the same thing as resize it down. I am curious that if you have compared the performance & quality of decreasing BITMAP_SCALE, vs the RenderScript Resize?

Comment: No Miao,I tried your solution with the 1.f/5.f resize scale,it didnt blur so much.Even nothing has changed :)

Comment: Oh, this is just an example to use Intrinsic Resize and it didn't use Blur. Try to change RESIZE_SCALE and dd a IntrinsicBlur after resize.